# Use variable from an instance of a class in a converter?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, converters

I have some code as follows:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
  public bool Adam = true;

  public MainWindow()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  public class NextEnabled : IValueConverter
  {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {

    return Adam;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
    return true;
   }
  }
 }
```

What I want my converter to return is the value of Adam.  I understand that it doesn't work right now because the converter class doesn't have a reference to an instance of MainWindow.  In the XAML, the main window is named "window_main", and I want to reference this instance - but can't.

Is there any way to do this?  Using `return window_main.Adam;` does not work either - it doesn't recognize this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using only a single instance of your main window, how about making it global? Of course, this is not the best approach, but I truly can't think of any other solution for your problem.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static MainWindow MainWindow;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool Adam = true;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Globals.MainWindow = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class NextEnabled : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Globals.MainWindow;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make NextEnabled like this

```
  public class NextEnabled : IValueConverter
  {
   protected Window window_main;
   public NextEnabled(Window w) { window_main = w; }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {

    return window_main.Adam;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
    return true;
   }
  }
```

You have to call this new constructor when you create NextEnabled.

Comment: Although I do not think this is the best approach, I cannot think of other, and your solution sure is the one that will work. Only one suggestion: perhaps the constructor should take reference value: public NextEnabled(ref Window w)

Comment: I don't understand how this would work, given that it's only constructed from XAML:

<Window.Resources>
 <local:NextEnabled x:Key="NextEnabled"/>
</Window.Resources>

Comment: Sorry, I don't know WPF -- try making a property called WindowMain of type Window, and then use an attribute in the XML to set it.